# Iterate over properties and assign values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, components

I have a component with properties. I want to assign new values to those properties when the input changes. Because I have many properties (they are used as text in an **svg template**) i want to iterate over them and assign new values to them.
I tried the following but without success and I can't figure out any working way.

```js
@Component({
selector: 'app-my-component',
templateUrl: './my.svg',
styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() aMapWithNewNumbers: Map<string,number>;
    
PropertieA = 1;
PropertieB = 2;
...
PropertieZ = 3;
    
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes.aMapWithNewNumbers.currentValue){
      const list = Object.key(this);
      list.forEach((elem) => {
        if(this.aMapWithNewNumbers.get(elem) != undefined){
          const num = this.aMapWithNewNumbers.get(elem);
          elem = num; //<= this doesn't work since elem is of type string
        }
      });
    }
}
...
```

My SVG template would look like this:

```xml
<svg ...>
...
<text ...>{{PropertieA}}</text>
<text ...>{{PropertieB}}</text>
...
<text ...>{{PropertieZ}}</text>
...
</svg>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the keys of a component object is not a common pattern, and usually another data structure can be used instead. In this case, I think you could just use the existing map Input in your html by binding to the it directly: `[myProp]="aMapWithNewNumbers?.get('myPropertyName')"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
var myProperties = {
    property1: true,
    property2: 25,
    property3: 'PropertyValue',
  };

for (const property in myProperties) {
    if (property === 'property1')
    {
        myProperties[property] = false;
    }
}

for (const property in myProperties) {
    
    console.log(property);
    console.log(myProperties[property]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If found the problem. I have to adress my propertie of the object with `this[elem]`. Than it works.
So the commented line would be

```
this[elem] = num;
```